# No mail-notifications on Ubuntu Phone (bq Aquaris E4.5)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, gmail, mail-notification

I have installed the gmail scope/app from Ubuntu Core App Developers but I dont receive any notifications for new emails (worked once a few days ago for one mail though!). What am I missing? There is no open instance of my gmail account on other devices. No updates missing on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that mail in conversation tagged "important" in your mail box always generate notifications but not the others which seems to generate notification randomly and very few time.