# No Gmail Notifications for Ubuntu Phone on Meizu MX4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gmail, meizu-mx4

I got my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu a couple of days ago and can't seem to get the GMail notifications working on it. I have two separate Google accounts set up, both of which allow access to the GMail app that came pre-installed on the phone, but there are no notifications when I receive new mails. Am I missing something?

(My question seems to be related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603621/no-mail-notifications-on-ubuntu-phone-bq-aquaris-e4-5), with the differences being the phone and the fact that I have never managed to receive any mail notification at all)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone and also use Gmail. I do get a very gentle tap when I receive an email, and a popup at the top of the screen, and a notification in the task bar. The sound is rather subtle but still quite noticeable. I can't find where to change the sound. I didn't change anything to get it working. I do know a few settings that might be connected to your problem, so just to make sure the obvious stuff is set correctly:

In System settings - Notifications, there should be a listing of all apps that are allowed to notify you. For me that's External drives, System Settings, Facebook, Gmail and Telegram. To the right of each entry is a radio button to switch it on or off.

So: is Gmail listed there? If so, and turned off, easy fix. If not, your account may not be OK. Go back to system settings and to Accounts (one to the left). There, Google should be listed with your mail address underneath. If so, enter it by tapping. At the top is your ID, below are the different apps that use Google account. Is Gmail shown? Is the button switched on?

If you're in doubt whether your account settings are correct, you could remove and add back your google account from the accounts settings.

Otherwise, I wouldn't know what to do... Good luck anyway!